# How do I prevent a video from going full screen when embedded using HTML5 and UIWebView?

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am embedding a video into my application using UIWebView. The desired behavior is for the video to not go full screen when the user presses play.
I am attempting to achieve this using

```
let HTMLString = 
"<iframe " +
        "src=\"https://streamable.com/e/2k8l?logo=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1\" " +
        "width=\"\(width-20)\" height=\"\(height-20)\" " +
        "webkit-playsinline>" +
"</iframe>"

webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
webView.loadHTMLString(HTMLString, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

Since this is a streamable link, "logo=0" removes the streamable logo. The autoplay is desired and is working just fine; however the code for playing the video "inline" is not working. I have looked over the iOS reference for UIWebView and additional requirement for setting `webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true` is that I have to add `"webkit-playsinline"` to my HTML string.

I don't use HTML very much at all, so I'm not too familiar with it and I simply cannot figure out why the video will go full-screen. Is it a restriction placed by Streamable?? I'm not sure I understand what is happening but I also read that going full-screen is the behavior in Safari and save for on iPads, an HTML embed will never play inline. But I am presumably not using Safari.

Furthermore a youtube link will play videos inline just fine. 
With the same code changing only the HTMLString like so:

```
let HTMLString = 
"<iframe " + 
    "width=\"\(width-20)\" height=\"\(height-20)\" " +
    "src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/OBmM79YadYM?autoplay=1&playsinline=1\">" +
"</iframe>"
```

the video will play inline like desired but will not autoplay. What is going on here? Is the behavior determined by source?